# Strange Results when trying to create JSON output from simple Python Array

Tags: python, graphene-python

I have written this code:

```
myarray = []
myarray.append('abc')
myarray.append('def')
return json.dumps(myarray)
```

This is part of a GraphQL function.  What I get back is the equivalent of this:

```
"myArray": "[\"abc\", \"def\"]"
```

How can I eliminate the backslashes?

Robert

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown enough code to reproduce this error. Presumably, whatever is calling this function is also converting to json. So you should return myarray directly, without converting to json in this function.

Answer (score 0):

My predicament turned out to be that GraphQL (via Graphene-Django) was already turning the array into JSON.  Thus I was effectively converting to JSON twice.  I solved the problem by just returning `myarray` directly.